# Переход между экранами, без Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Совершаю переход между экранами при помощь кнопки "Войти"

```
ViewControllerTable *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerTable"];
                  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Но такой вариант работает, только если к 1 экрану присоединен навигатор(1 скриншот)
Но нужно, чтобы навигатор был только у второго экрана, при этом, при запуске приложения вызывался первый экран, а не навигатор, который указывает на экран 2(визуальное представление скриншот 2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `IB` укажите `Storyboard ID` для нужного Вам контроллера и затем перейти по указанному `ID`:

```
    SecondViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_ID"];
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Второй вариант через `IB`, выделяете вашу кнопку, правый клик (удерживаю кнопку зажатой) и ведете к новому контроллеру и затем выбираете тип соединения.